# Apache Flink Rest-Client Jar-Upload not working

Tags: apache-flink

I am struggling to automatically deploy new Flink jobs within our CI/CD workflows by using the Flink rest-api (which may be found [here in the flink Github repository](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/docs/monitoring/rest_api.md)).

Documentation only says that that jar upload may be achieved by using `/jars/upload`, but not how exactly a valid rest request has to be build (which `Headers`, which `Body` type, which `Authorization`, which `Method` and so on).

So I took a look at the Flink dashboard code of `flink/flink-runtime-web` project on Github and searched for [the implementation](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime-web/web-dashboard/app/scripts/modules/submit/submit.ctrl.coffee) they used to upload a jar and - Yippie! Its implemented by calling the rest-api I am trying to use (using `POST` as method). After that I tried to figure out with Postman which is correct way to send requests using different `Content-Type` headers and `Body` types, but none of them worked for me now.

I would have filed a ticket directly to the flink project, but could not find any reference to their ticket system.

**So the basic Question here is**:

- How do I have to call the rest endpoint `/jars/upload` to successfully upload a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've run into the same issue and solved it by looking at the network request in chrome when uploading a jar with the web UI.

The request must

- Use multipart upload
- The field name **must** be jarfile
- The multi part content **must** include the file Content-Type as well (otherwise you'll get a 500 from Flink complaining about the missing header)

Here is a python script using requests that does the upload

```
upload = requests.post(                                                                                               
    base_url + "/jars/upload",                                                                                        
    files={
        "jarfile": (
            os.path.basename(path), 
            open(path, "rb"), 
            "application/x-java-archive"
         )
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Item 3 'application/x-java-archive' is the key, which resolved for me as well.

Comment: What about deleting old jar files, any idea?

Answer (score 10):

Those who are more partial to a command line can use curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Expect:" -F "jarfile=@path/to/flink-job.jar" http://hostname:8081/jars/upload
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I actually missed the ``@path`` and struggled for some time.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want a java solution can use:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("YOUR API URL");
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addBinaryBody("jarfile", new File("jarr.jar"));
        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

        try{
            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println(response);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```